# Building KDE from source?

Tags: compiling, kde, source

I am trying build the kde from the source available on https://www.kde.org/info/4.14.3.php, but I am a bit lost about the order of installation of the packages listed on the page, which would give me a hint about the minimum required packages to make the system work. Anyone can indicate to me some link with this order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last time I had to build KDE from scratch I used [this](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/kde/kde.html) as a guide. It is from Linux From Scratch (in particular Beyond Linux From Scratch) and should help you through everything.

A quick copy and paste shows this order:

- Automoc4-0.9.88
- Phonon-4.8.2
- Phonon-backend-gstreamer-4.8.0
- Phonon-backend-vlc-0.8.1
- Akonadi-1.13.0
- Attica-0.4.2
- QImageblitz-0.0.6
- Polkit-Qt-0.112.0
- Oxygen-icons-4.14.3
- Kdelibs-4.14.3
- Kfilemetadata-4.14.3
- Kdepimlibs-4.14.3
- Baloo-4.14.3
- Baloo-widgets-4.14.3
- Polkit-kde-agent-0.99.0
- Kactivities-4.13.3
- Kde-runtime-4.14.3
- Kde-baseapps-4.14.3
- Kde-base-artwork-4.14.3
- Kde-workspace-4.11.14

Good luck!

Comment: quick question: I really need install both Phonon-backend-gstreamer and Phonon-backend-vlc? If I prefer vlc, I could install only this last one?

Comment: @KleberMota honestly, I don't know. I prefer vlc as well, but last time I built KDE I did both.

Answer (score 1):

You want to follow these instructions: [Building KDE Frameworks 5](https://community.kde.org/Frameworks/Building) or [Building KDE SC 4.x](https://techbase.kde.org/Getting_Started/Build/kdesrc-build).  These guides use a very handy script called kdesrc-build.  It is a tool provided by the KDE community to automate and simplify building and updating KDE from source.  It uses simple text file to configure exactly what you want to install and how you want to install it.  It also helps handle behind-the-scenes stuff like renames, splits, or merges in the KDE git repos.